# How to copy specific lines from file 1 after specific line from file 2?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a `file1` and a `file2`.

I want to copy lines 3,4,5 of `file1` into `file2`, but after line 3.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
sed -i 3r<(sed '3,5!d' file1) file2
```

Any ideas? (I work with a macOS)

Example file1:

```
_line_1;
_line_2;
_line_3;
_line_4;
_line_5;
```

Example file2:

```
line1;
line2;
line3;
line4;
```

Example output

```
line1;
line2;
line3;
_line_3;
_line_4;
_line_5;
line4;
```

Comment: `sed '3,5!d' file1 > tmpfile` `sed -i 3rtmpfile file2` ?

Comment: Why did you tag this linux if you're on a mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a mix of `ed` and `sed`:

```
printf "%s\n" '3r !sed -n 3,5p file1' w | ed -s file2
```

Inserts the results of the sed command after line 3 of file2. Said sed prints out lines 3 through 5 of file1. Then it saves the changed file2.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '3,5p' file1 | sed '3r /dev/stdin' file2
```

Turn off implicit printing in the first sed invocation and pipe the results (lines 3-5) from file1 to a second sed invocation that reads in these lines after line 3 of file2.

Answer (score 0):

With only ed if it's allowed

```
printf "%s\n" "kx" "r file1" "'x+3,'x+5m3" "'x+1,\$d" "w" | ed -s file2
```

Here the k command mark the last line of file2.
You must protect the $ to the shell.